# How to pass nested objects from jsp pages to Spring MVC through jQuery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have a form which contains some datafields and I have to pass some corresponding objects to be updated all together in a Spring controller. I'm not achieving to do it due to Spring thrown errors in matter of "Field error in object [parentObject] on field [nestedObject]".

For what I imagine that I'm not dealing with these objects correctly. How can I manipulate this objects in order to Spring MVC recognize and manage it properly?

Here goes the codes:

Corresponding piece of JSP page:

```
                        <form id="fmActivity"
                              method="post"
                              accept-charset="iso-8859-1,utf-8" 
                              novalidate>
                            <div class="fitem">
                                <label>Description</label> 
                                <textarea id="description" name="description" class="easyui-validatebox" required cols="40" rows="5">
                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fitem">
                                <label>Comments</label>
                                 <textarea id="comments" name="comments" class="easyui-validatebox" cols="40" rows="5">
                                 </textarea>
                            </div>
                            <!-- HERE ARE THE PROBLEMS: PROJECT, EXECUTOR AND DATETIME FIELDS ARE NOT PROCESSED BY SPRING 
                            <div class="fitem">
                                <label>Project (it would be hidden)</label>
                                <input id="project" type="hidden" name="project" class="easyui-validatebox" required value="${project}">
                            </div> 
                            <div class="fitem">
                                <label>Executor (it would be hidden)</label>
                                <input id="executor" type="hidden" name="executor" class="easyui-validatebox" required value="${executor}">
                            </div> 
                            <div class="fitem">
                                <label>Date/Time</label>
                                <input id="dateTime" class="easyui-datetimebox" required name="dateTime" style="width:150px">
                            </div>
                            --> 
                            <div class="fitem">
                                <label>Tag</label>
                                <input name="tag" class="easyui-validatebox" required>
                            </div>
                                <input id="button1" name="button1" type="submit" value="submit">
                        </form>
```

The JQuery code to process the button click:

```
$('input#button1').click( function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ActivityUpdate',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('form#fmActivity').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                         },
                error: function(errobj, str, errt){
                    alert(str + " " + errt);
                }
            });
        });
```

And the MVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ActivityUpdate")
public String update(Activity activity, HttpSession httpSession) {
    Session sess = (Session) httpSession.getAttribute("hibSess");
    ActivityDAO actDao = new ActivityDAO(sess);
    actDao.persist(activity);
    return "forward:ActivityList";
}
```

When I try to do the processing without the objects PROJECT, EXECUTOR and the DateTime, it works. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: can you do a console.log on $('form#fmActivity').serialize() and post the results please (of the case where u get an error)?

Comment: Why don't you use `@ModelAttribute` instead?